# Empty and/or Filter ObjectStorage objects

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I have an object `appointment` with a property `expertises` of type `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Vendor\Extname\Domain\Model\Expertise>`.
Additionally one important property of `Expertise` is the bool `checked`.

What I want to do in my AppointmentController is:

1. In the first action: Empty the `appointment`'s property `expertises` (not set it to `NULL`, I just want an empty `ObjectStorage` that I can add something to later)
2. In the second action: Fill `appointment` with `expertises` (from a different object) whose property `checked` equals `true`

To start out with the emptying I looked at the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246604/typo3-extbase-how-to-empty-objectstorage) but it didn't work for me.
This is what I tried:

```
 $appExp = $appointment->getExpertises();
 foreach ($appExp as $exp) {
     $appExp->detach($exp);
 }     
 \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($appointment);
```

But it shows that all `expertises` are still in `appointment`.

In the second action I do this:

```
foreach ($expertises as $expertise) {
    if ($expertise->getChecked()) {
        $appointment->addExpertise($expertise);
    }
}
```

It works, but I wonder if there's an easier "filter" function that can automatically filter the `checked` value and return an `ObjectStorage` object. Because this way I could just use `setExpertises()` and the old ones would get overwritten which would make the first step unnecessary.

So does someone have an idea for the emptying and filtering of `ObjectStorage` objects?
I looked a bit into the [ObjectStorage Class reference](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_persistence_1_1_object_storage.html) but there's no obvious function that empties it (`removeAll` ist just for *objects contained in another storage from the current storage*) and no filter function either.

Comment: Well, at least to empty an ObjectStorage just create a new one and use it. Often using this solution for ObjectStorage getters like setExpertise - just give a new Storage to the function. But some days ago I've seen someone on SO for which this solution does not work.

Comment: Can I create it like this or would another way be better? (I'm a bit confused after reading about many different ways to instantiate objects in Typo3) `$emptyStorage = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy way to remove all objects from the object storage:

```
$appointment->getExpertises()->removeAll($appointment->getExpertises());
```

As for filtering: as you already noticed, you have to do it yourself. I would implement such functions like `getActiveExpertises` in the Model, because it fits there much better than in a controller.

Answer (score 0):

The setters in ExtbaseObjects that refer to ObjectStorages have an optional parameter that defaults to null. Just call the setter without a parameter. You don't have to waste performance by instanciating an empty StorageObject.

```
$appointment->setExpertises();
```

Comment: pls try to add some explanation code only answers are discouraged in SO.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.