# TYPO3 Extension: FE user should be able to add properties to a record/object - Is this possible?

Tags: typo3

Is there a way to add properties (and delete them) in the frontend?

Example:

I have an object of the type Storage. This object has the boolean property $full and additional to that the object of the type Storage has a 1:1 relation with an object of the type Storagespace. Now we get to my problem: In the real world you can put as many shelves as you want into a storage, either 2 big shelves or 4 smaller ones. Back to my extension: The frontend user should be able to add as many boolean properties (shelf_a, shelf_b, shelf_c) to the object Storagespace as he wants. The user should be able to set each property to true and if all those properties are set to true the property $full the related object Storage should be set to true.

My question: Is it possible to create such a class in my extension? Is it possible for the Frontend user to add properties to an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot dynamically add new properties to a model (you can only set values), but you can add elements to a property (aka sub-properties).

As such your idea with the n:m relation will work.

The property to hold those related objects would be a [ObjectStorage](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/8/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_persistence_1_1_object_storage.html) with an appropriate TCA-definition.

You will have to tell your controller how to handle incoming HTTP-values and add/remove objects to your ObjectStorage in an initializeXXXAction().

```
$mappingConfiguration = $this->arguments[$argumentName]->getPropertyMappingConfiguration();
$mappingConfiguration->allowAllProperties();
$mappingConfiguration->forProperty($property)
  ->setTypeConverterOption(
    'TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\TypeConverter\PersistentObjectConverter', 
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\TypeConverter\PersistentObjectConverter::CONFIGURATION_CREATION_ALLOWED, 
    TRUE
  )
  ->allowAllProperties();
```

It is possible within a single Extbase-action that updates the whole object although from my experience it is easier to get a nice form with add/delete functionality with multiple actions that are called via AJAX.

Comment: Currently i get an error when trying to add an object to the object storage: 'Call to a member function attach() on null ' 

I use code that resembles this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246604/typo3-extbase-how-to-empty-objectstorage

Comment: Be sure to initialize your ObjectStorages in the model's __construct(). `$this->myprop = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();`

Comment: It seems that i just can't get the TCAs right. I constantly get the error: 'Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'checklist' at row 1 ' Checklist is my ObjectStorage.

Answer (score 1):

short answer: YES (SCNR), everything you program is possible.

Specify your question how this could be programmed. give an example how would you solve it.

Comment: My only solution would be creating another class (Shelves) which has a m:n relation to Storagespace. The user would be easily able to create as many shelve objects as he want and each would have a property ($full)... Don't know... But that doesn't look as elegant...

Comment: question: are there infinite shelves, or is there a maximum? second: anything a FE user could do must be foreseen and programmed. if a user should be able to add a record (any kind) a form for this must be created and all inputs must be validated and then a record could be generated. if you want to delete a record: form, validation and processing. records with relations: the same with reference to the preselected record. ...

Comment: I haven't looked into it yet, but would my initial plan work with value objects? As far as i understand value objects don't have defined properties. Or do i missunderstand the concept of value objects?

Comment: The _natural_ way would be a relation to records of type shelve. And with a suitable definition you can add as much shelves as you like. Of course you can add all the shelves information into one field using XML, JSON or similar, but that only would make access complicated and is no other way than a covert relation.

Comment: I see... Currently i'm trying to combine this idea (records of type shelve) with the recommendation above (object storage) to be able to easily check if all objects of type shelve or rather their property $full is true or false.